# How to remove the first and last lines from a zipped file in linux

Tags: linux

Iam having a zipped file A.gz . How can I remove the first and last line from the file and put the rest in a new file? The command that I have tried is:

```
zcat A.gz|sed -i '1d;$d' >B
```

Comment: You don't need `-i`.

Comment: This will only work is there is only 1 file in the zip file I think.

Comment: Without giving -i also iam getting an error "gzip: A.gz: unexpected end of file"

Comment: Can we use any other command other than this sed command?

Comment: Do you get this error after running `zcat A.gz` without `sed`?

Answer (score 1):

A test I ran that works:

```
zcat file.gz
```

yields

```
hello
yellow
world
```

We edit the file...

```
zcat file.gz | head -n-1 | tail -n-1 | gzip > edited.gz
```

The result is

```
zcat edited.gz
yellow
```